# Angular 5 parent child data sharing

Tags: angular

I'm working on angular 5.
I have one array of objects on parent component which I need to show in child component, If any value gets changed in that array of object, I want parent component's value should also be updated.
Now My question is,
Angular provides 3 ways for component intrection.

1. **@Input @output** decorators
2. **@viewchild** decorator
3. Using **Services**

Which One is more Efficient?
Which is best approach In my case? or In general parent child data sharing?

Comment: I would suggest to use @input decorator to pass the array the child component, because it is the easiest one for your scenario

Comment: you should use @Input with Two-way binding ( [(...)] )

Comment: @Alessandro How is it more effient anong these three?

Comment: Your child component will expose an @Input property that your parent component will bind in two way fashion style, It's like to have an input property and a property change event on the child component, I suggest you to take a look to https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use service approach for updated data handles, following is code

create a `data-sharing.service.ts` file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataSharingService {

  private dataSource  = new BehaviorSubject<any>('null');
  currentData = this.dataSource.asObservable();


  private activeStateData  = new BehaviorSubject<any>('null');
  currentActive = this.activeStateData.asObservable();
  constructor() { }

  changeData(data:any){
    this.dataSource.next(data);
  }

  aciveState(state:string){
    this.activeStateData.next(state);
  }    
}
```

**from parent component**

```
constructor( private alertService: AlertService)
  add() {
    let yourSharingData = null;
    this.dataService.changeData(yourSharingData );
    this.router.navigate(["/path-to-your-child"]);
  }
```

**from child component subscribe the service**

```
this.dataService.currentData.subscribe(res => {
console.log(res);
})
```

Answer (score 4):

1. One component (`<comp1>`) is used inside the template of another component  (`<comp2>`). Use **@Input @Output**

   - as both components will be in a parent-child relationship
   - simple and best to exchange data to/from the child component
2. Two different components (`<comp1>, <comp2>`) are used inside a third component's temperate (`<comp3>`). Use **service** (only for small apps, not recommended for large apps)

   - both components (comp1, comp2) are not directly related
   - as two components are not in parent-child relation, @Input @Output wont work here
   - Alternatively, you can **also use ngrx/store library for large apps** (state management)
3. I use **@ViewChild** to mainly observe for changes in a DOM element and perform my stuff based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Let me demonstrate them..

- `@Input()` and `@Output()` used usually to **pass specific variables** between *parent* and *child* components.

  Where `@Input()` used to pass variable from *parent* to *child* and `@Output()` used to pass from variable from *child* to *parent*.
- `@ViewChild()` used to get control for *child* component inside *parent* component.

  When you use it; you can catch the *child* component as an **Object**, so you can call its functions, edit its variables and so on.
- **Services** (if you use it to pass variables) will be like a global variable that any component use this service can see it, not just between `parent` and `child` components.

  From my point of view; you should not use services to pass data from `parent` to `child` or vice versa; cause you'll face a lot of issues if you use multiple child component of use a child component twice.

Answer (score 0):

If you asked about efficiency considering the performance with large data sets, then it is better to choose service than "@output" because it internally uses EventEmitters which are costly on performance and same goes with the change detection as well. I hope this answers your question.