# How to replace onchange lifecycle to changeDetection?

Tags: angular

I am doing parent child communication for chart display

Comment: What about creating service with behavior subject and passing data?

Comment: @Chellappan yes please a way how to do i don't know how to do it. Please help

Comment: check this tutorial:https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55215757/angular-5-parent-child-data-sharing